# Converting dictionary into two-column panda dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I have a dictionary in python called `word_counts` consisting of key words and values which represent the frequency in which they appear in a given text:

```
word_counts = {'the':2, 'cat':2, 'sat':1, 'with':1, 'other':1}
```

I now need to make this into a pandas DataFrame with two columns: a column named 'word' indicating the words and column named 'count' indicating the frequency.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> pd.DataFrame(list(word_counts.items()), columns=['word', 'count'])
    word  count
0    the      2
1    cat      2
2    sat      1
3   with      1
4  other      1
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

you can create a dataframe from a dictonary:

```
df=pd.DataFrame({"word":list(word_counts.keys()) , "count": list(word_counts.values())})
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the `.from_dict` appendage from `pd.DataFrame`

```
pd.DataFrame.from_dict(word_counts, orient="index", columns=["Count"]).rename_axis(
    "Word", axis=1
)
Word   Count
the        2
cat        2
sat        1
with       1
other      1
```